# Rust Trait warning: method references the `Self` type in its `where` clause

Tags: asynchronous, rust, traits

We're trying to create a pointer to a trait object and getting a warning that the trait cannot be made into an object.

```
use async_trait::async_trait;
use std::sync::{Arc, Weak};

fn main() {
    println!("Hello, world!");
}

pub type MyTraitPtr = Arc<dyn MyTrait>;

#[async_trait]
pub trait MyTrait {
    async fn foo(&self) {}
}

pub struct Parent {
    child: MyTraitPtr,
}
```

This produces the following warning:

```
warning: the trait `MyTrait` cannot be made into an object
  --> src/main.rs:14:14
   |
14 |     async fn foo(&self) {}
   |              ^^^
   |
   = note: `#[warn(where_clauses_object_safety)]` on by default
   = warning: this was previously accepted by the compiler but is being phased out; it will become a hard error in a future release!
   = note: for more information, see issue #51443 <https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/51443>
note: for a trait to be "object safe" it needs to allow building a vtable to allow the call to be resolvable dynamically; for more information visit <https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/items/traits.html#object-safety>
  --> src/main.rs:14:14
   |
13 | pub trait MyTrait {
   |           ------- this trait cannot be made into an object...
14 |     async fn foo(&self) {}
   |              ^^^ ...because method `foo` references the `Self` type in its `where` clause
   = help: consider moving `foo` to another trait
```

Full code: https://github.com/lunar-mining/trait_ptr

Update: if we add Sync to the Trait definition then it compiles, like so:

```
use std::sync::{Arc, Weak};

fn main() {
    println!("Hello, world!");
}

pub type MyTraitPtr = Arc<dyn MyTrait>;

#[async_trait]
pub trait MyTrait: Sync {
    async fn foo(&self) {}
}

pub struct Parent {
    child: MyTraitPtr,
}
```

However if the trait's methods take an Arc reference to Self, then it does not compile:

```
use async_trait::async_trait;
use std::sync::{Arc, Weak};

fn main() {
    println!("Hello, world!");
}

pub type MyTraitPtr = Arc<dyn MyTrait>;

#[async_trait]
pub trait MyTrait: Sync {
    async fn foo(self: Arc<Self>) {}
}

pub struct Parent {
    child: MyTraitPtr,
}
```

Discussion of the problem here: https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/51443

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can implement that by moving the implementation out of the trait:

```
use async_trait::async_trait;
use std::sync::{Arc, Weak};

pub type MyTraitPtr = Arc<dyn MyTrait>;

#[async_trait]
pub trait MyTrait {
    async fn foo(&self);
}

impl dyn MyTrait {
    async fn foo(&self) { }
}

pub struct Parent {
    child: MyTraitPtr,
}
```

You can also implement that directly to Arc:

```
pub type MyTraitPtr = Arc<dyn MyTrait>;

#[async_trait]
pub trait MyTrait: Sync + Send {
    async fn foo(&self);
}

#[async_trait]
impl MyTrait for MyTraitPtr {
    async fn foo(&self) { }
}

pub struct Parent {
    child: MyTraitPtr,
}
```

Answer (score 2):

From [`async-trait` docs](https://docs.rs/async-trait/latest/async_trait/#dyn-traits):

> ### [Dyn traits](https://docs.rs/async-trait/latest/async_trait/#dyn-traits)
>
> Traits with async methods can be used as trait objects as long as they meet the usual requirements for dyn – no methods with type parameters, no self by value, no associated types, etc.
>
> ...
>
> The one wrinkle is in traits that provide default implementations of async methods. In order for the default implementation to produce a future that is Send, the async_trait macro must emit a bound of `Self: Sync` on trait methods that take `&self` and a bound `Self: Send` on trait methods that take &mut self. An example of the former is visible in the expanded code in the explanation section above.
>
> If you make a trait with async methods that have default implementations, everything will work except that the trait cannot be used as a trait object. Creating a value of type `&dyn Trait` will produce an error that looks like this:
>
> ```
> error: the trait `Test` cannot be made into an object
>  --> src/main.rs:8:5
>   |
> 8 |     async fn cannot_dyn(&self) {}
>   |     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
> ```
>
> For traits that need to be object safe and need to have default implementations for some async methods, there are two resolutions. Either you can add Send and/or Sync as supertraits (Send if there are `&mut self` methods with default implementations, Sync if there are `&self` methods with default implementations) to constrain all implementors of the trait such that the default implementations are applicable to them:
>
> ```rust
> #[async_trait]
> pub trait ObjectSafe: Sync {  // added supertrait
>     async fn can_dyn(&self) {}
> }
>
> let object = &value as &dyn ObjectSafe;
> ```
>
> or you can strike the problematic methods from your trait object by bounding them with `Self: Sized`:
>
> ```rust
> #[async_trait]
> pub trait ObjectSafe {
>     async fn cannot_dyn(&self) where Self: Sized {}
>
>     // presumably other methods
> }
>
> let object = &value as &dyn ObjectSafe;
> ```

`Arc` is considered the same as mutable references in this regard, and requires a `Send` bound. See also [the bug report I posted to `async-trait`](https://github.com/dtolnay/async-trait/issues/210).